# Spring HttpSecurity overwrite response header

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

You can add a header to a response by doing

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CacheControl extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .headers()
      .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=43200"));
  }
}
```

If the response already has a Cache-Control property, this just adds a second one to it with the same name:

```
Cache-Control: original content
Cache-Control: added content
```

Is there an easy way to overwrite the existing property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I found was to disable Cache-Control, and then to add the Cache-Control header again.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CacheControlAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  public CacheControlAdapter() {}

  @Override
  @RequestMapping("/app/")
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    StaticHeadersWriter writer = new StaticHeadersWriter("Cache-Control", "value");
    http
      .headers()
      .cacheControl()
      .disable()
      .addHeaderWriter(writer);
  }
}
```